# How can I match the most nested comment with a regular expression?

Tags: regex

I'm struggling with a regex. I can't find a way to extract the most nested comment in this example:

```
/* test
/* sec/*o*
new line
n*/d */
*/
```

To be clear, what I want to extract is the following:

```
/*o*
new line
n*/
```

So far i can select it only if it doesn't have a `*` character, using this regex:

```
/\*[^\*]*\*/
```

But I can't figure out how to exclude this particular string: `/*`, 
and I can't find the right keywords to get my answer on the web.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a regex question but the mandatory mention of the tool/language is missing

Comment: Do you want to just match the nested comments at the first level? Please mention the programming language.

Comment: @DenysSéguret That's not a good close reason, that's a reason to post a comment asking for more details.

Comment: @Barmar I disagree. It's just like "not clear enough" but it's more constructive for OP (and passing by readers)

Comment: If you need to match any comment that has no nested comments, you do not even need any recursion or balanced constructs. And as for "memory": what about capturing groups and back-references? Try [`/\*(?:(?!/\*|\*/)[\s\S])*\*/`](https://regex101.com/r/wU6vT8/1) regex.

Comment: @stribizhev: you're right -- this question is about the *most* nested comment, not about finding all nested comments (or stuff like that). Sorry for the nuisance!

Comment: @DenysSéguret If I find a question unclear, I ask for clarification. If none comes (or their attempts are just as lacking), then I vote to close as unclear what you're asking.

Comment: Thank you @stribizhev, you answered my question! I don't really understand the remarks that were done, they seem irrelevant to me. Maybe i was unclear, anyway you got it!

Comment: People here want everything to be crystal clear. You should just add that requirement to your question. I posted the answer with a link to the main regex structure used in it.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Regex is a very clear thing in the computer science, it has even a mathematical definition. It is clearly a language-independent thing.

Comment: @peterh Flavors and tools are very very important for regexes. Most questions get very different answers depending on that precision. To learn about regexes, I'd suggest you to start by reading the description of the regex tag in SO (see the *"Remember to include a tag specifying the programming language or tool you are using"* ?). Then [this meta question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/290740/provide-asking-instructions-for-regex-just-like-for-sql).

Comment: @DenysSéguret I don't see so significant difference between the different regex implementations. Maybe in the supported abbrevations there is a little difference. But the features of the regexes, as it in [theory of the formal languages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_language_theory) exists, is supported practically everywhere, and it is (at least in theory) enough to solve any regex problem. Sometimes, especially in microsoft environment, patterns are called regexes, but it is only a faulty terminology.

Comment: @DenysSéguret Any SQL implementations, including ms-sql (called mistakenly "SQL" in the meta post), uses either a bad regex (which isn't regex in its formal language sense), or has some extension to use perl-compatible regexes (which are called through some external library calls).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can match any last-level nested comments (those that do not have any more nested comments) with the help of the [**tempered greedy token**](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-quantifiers.html#tempered_greed):

```
/\*(?:(?!/\*|\*/)[\s\S])*\*/
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/wU6vT8/1)